# Posting a Q&A on Super User didn't work and gave me no error message

Tags: bug

I actually don't know how to reproduce this bug. In a nutshell, I tried posting a question and answer (together) on Super User. Every time I hit the submit button, the page would reload, with all my content intact. No question was posted, and no error message was showing.

The details can be be found [on this Meta SU post](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12732/266405). The bottom line is: although the answer for why it probably didn't work was found (connecting from a location with multiple users behind one IP address), I still should have received an error message, and I received none.

Happened on Chrome OS, version 62.0.3202.74.